# Auto percentage width based on children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jQuery code which automatically gives a div a percentage width based on the number of children which works well until you have more divs within the child div, how can I get this to ignore any divs inside the child ".eaService" and just give ".eaService" the calculated width.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var el = $('.servCon .eaService');
var len = el.children().length;
if (len > 0) {
    len = 100 / len;
    el.css("width", len + "%");
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="servCon">
        <div class="eaService">
            <div class="imgPanel"><img src="someimage.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="pad">
                <h3>Sub Heading</h3>
                <p>At Smith Jones we are committed to forming close partnerships with our clients, enabling us to understand... Find our more</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eaService">
            <div class="imgPanel"><img src="someimage.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="pad">
                <h3>Sub Heading</h3>
                <p>At Smith Jones we are committed to forming close partnerships with our clients, enabling us to understand... Find our more</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With  `var el = $('.servCon .eaService');` you are selecting both `.eaService divs`

so, when you call `var len = el.children().length;` you are getting the sum of  their childrens, in this case it is `4`, so then you are setting to .`eaService` width of 25%;

You should modify your code like here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var el = $('.servCon');
var childs=$('.eaService');
var len = el.children().length;
if (len > 0) {
    len = 100 / len;
    childs.css("width", len + "%");
}
});
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're specifically selecting the children of .eaService here, it's no wonder that you're counting up those elements.

What you're doing is `$(".servCon .eaService").children()`, which first selects *all* of your .eaService elements (in this case two) and then finds the children of those elements. The resulting selection includes both .imgPanel divs and both .pad divs.

What you *probably* mean to do is just find how many children .servCon has. So you want to do this:

```
var len = $(".servCon").children().length;
```

For maximum concision:

```
$(function(){
    $(".servCon").css("width", (100 / Math.max(1, $(".servCon").children().length)) + "%");
});
```